# Error 425 occuring every time I use PUT or LIST command on Windows 10

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I've tried pasv and port and nothing works.
Here is the commands and responses copied from my console:

```
ftp> user dlpuser
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> pwd
257 "/"
ftp> cd dir1
550 Failed to change directory.
ftp> mkd dir1
257 "/dir1" created
ftp> mkd dir2
257 "/dir2" created
ftp> cd dir1
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> put test.txt
425 Use PORT or PASV first.
ftp> quote pasv
227 Entering Passive Mode (44,241,66,173,4,19).
ftp> put test.txt
425 Failed to establish connection.
```